# Cannot access a collection in Angular-Meteor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, meteor, angular-meteor

I am trying to work with data from a Collection in Angular-Meteor, but so far I fail to access it.

In **lib/collections.js** I define the collection:

```
UserMeta = new Mongo.Collection('userMeta');
```

**server/publish.js** publishes it:

```
Meteor.publish('userMeta', function() {
  return UserMeta.find();
});
```

and in my client code **client/scripts/controllers/settings.controller.js** I subscribe:

```
angular
  .module('App')
  .controller('SettingsCtrl', SettingsCtrl);

function SettingsCtrl($scope, $reactive) {
  $reactive(this).attach($scope);
  this.subscribe('userMeta');
  //...
}
```

I have discovered that there seem to be multiple ways to subscribe (even used inconsistently in the official tutorial from Angular-Meteor), but I have decided to use the most recent syntax for v.1.3.2: [Subscribe API](http://www.angular-meteor.com/api/1.3.2/subscribe)

But if I want to view the whole content of the collection, it returns an empty array:

```
console.log(UserMeta.find().fetch()); // =[]
```

Or:

```
console.log(UserMeta.findOne()); // =undefined
```

However, if I run these commands in the client console in my browser, the expected results are returned.

Can somebody please give me a short example, how I can work with my collections? I am used to the way (pure) Meteor handles this and am confused that it does not seem to be as simple in Angular-Meteor.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
Meteor.Methods
```

On your Server side call

```
Meteor.methods({
getUserMeta: function () {
 var data = UserMeta.find({}).fetch();
 return data;
}
```

All call this method on server side using

```
 Meteor.call('getUserMeta',function (err, data) {
   if (!err) {
     Console.log(data);
   } else {
     console.log("error");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use Collection in console.log it isn't ready yet and hasn't any data.
You can use console.log inside helpers or you should check if collection is ready like this:

```
// Client-side
var subs = Meteor.subscribe('lastMsgRead', Meteor.userId());
Meteor.autorun(function() {
  if (subs.ready()) { ... }
});
```